# How to use Jenkins's environmnet variables(e.g.username,password) in cypress.config.js file to execute the cypress test

Tags: jenkins, cypress

We are trying to execute the cypress test cases on Jenkins.
We are using custom image of cypress/included:12.0.0 where all the required npm modules have been installed under /e2e/ directory.

The first cypress test case is login and the login details have been taken from the cypress.config.js file where username and password have been hardcoded for now in cypress.config.js file. The login details we are restoring using session for the rest of the cypress test cases.

We want to remove the hardcoding of the login details from the cypress.config.js file. Is there any way to use Jenkins's environment variables(e.g.username,password) in cypress.config.js file to execute the cypress test

We tried to use withcredentials option of jenkins . With this option while executing cypress run we can pass username and password with --env option.
We want to Jenkins's environment variables(e.g.username,password) in cypress.config.js file to execute the cypress test

Answer (score 0):

Any environment variable prepended with `CYPRESS_` will be interpreted by Cypress as a cypress environment variable. Assuming your variables consumed by Cypress would be `LOGIN_USER` and `LOGIN_PASSWORD`, you could make use of the environment block and the credentials plugin in your Jenkinsfile like so:

```
...
environment: {
  CYPRESS_LOGIN_USER = credentials('login-user-credential')
  CYPRESS_LOGIN_PASSWORD = credentials('login-password-credential')
}
...
```

These variables can then be used in your Cypress tests via `Cypress.env('name-of-variable')`, such as `Cypress.env('LOGIN_USER')`.